# CSS responsive pagination

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a project https://ikeen.com/blog, I'm using standard bootstrap pagination style there for my pagination according to online documentation. However I can't make it be on one line in the mobile version (no wrapping). That's the code for pagination:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination ml-3">
        <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">Назад</a></li>
        <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link">1</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="blog?page_no=2">2</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="blog?page_no=3">3</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="blog?page_no=4">4</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="blog?page_no=5">5</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="blog?page_no=6">6</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="blog?page_no=2">Далее</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="blog?page_no=6">Последняя ››</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For me it looks perfectly normal. However it looks awful on site.
[image]

If you have time to look at site you will find that it's inside `<div class="container>` so it should work. There is nothing I'm doing that is not according to documentation. Can you help me on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give your `.pagination` element flex wrap properties by using the Bootstrap `flex-wrap` class

```
<ul class="pagination flex-wrap ml-3">
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Why wouldn't bootstrap developers add this by default to pagination element? Don't you think it makes total sense?

Comment: I somewhat agree, but at the same time, it may be on the discretion of the developer on what UX they want to go with. Wrapping is one way to do this, but you can also have a x-axis scroll experience, or perhaps hide the other page numbers that don't fit in the screen, etc

Comment: Ok in some weird universe it might be the case. But don't you think it worths at least mentioning it on their doc page? First time I see bootstrap guys not at their best. Again thanks for the answer will accept it as soon as I can.